# Execute a Typescript file in VSCode with a shortcut key

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

Good day. I have a simple problem/question.

Given that I have a **TypeScript** file open and active in VSCode, is it possible to execute that script in the integrated terminal via a keyboard shortcut key?

To illustrate the issue better, right now I am doing exactly the same for **Javascript** files, with the help of a extension called [Node.js Exec](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miramac.vscode-exec-node).

> Run the current file or the code you selected with node.js.

No surprise here, when I press the F8 key (which is the designated extension shortcut key), it opens a terminal and executes the script.

[image]

I am looking for a way to do the exact same thing but with **typescript** files, either with another similar extension or other means, as long as it does the job.

I am also aware that TypeScript need to be compiled to plain Javascript first, so I was looking at [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) which lets you directly execute TypeScript on Node.js without precompiling, but I am not exactly sure how to go about the whole setup.

---

**Update**: Adding the following `launch.json` in your `.vscode` folder does the job.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run current .ts with ts-node",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "ts-node",
            "program": "${file}",
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT March 2023:**

It's easier to use the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) installed globally.

If your project's `package.json` is using ES modules (which it should because it's 2023), then you want to edit your VSCode `settings.json` and give the `ts-node` executable the `--esm` flag.

```json
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "typescript": "ts-node --esm"
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's solved, add it as an answer.

Comment: @Darvesh how do I add the edit I made as an answer?

Comment: Copy and paste.